# Composer package installed through php v7.1 but not php v7.2

Tags: php, composer-php

In my *Homestead* development environment, I've tried to install a composer package called `ralouphie/getallheaders` through php **v7.1**; it's done successfully. But when I am trying through php **v7.2**, it does not install that package; rather it creates the directory `ralouphie/getallheaders` without its contents.

Now, I have no idea why the package is not being installed through 7.2.

Update: When I ran this command: `php7.1 $(which composer) require ralouphie/getallheaders -vvv`, the output became as follows:

```sh
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): hg branch
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): fossil branch list
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): fossil tag list
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): svn info --xml
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin Hirak\Prestissimo\Plugin
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
    1/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-latest$786c0a2de55894abbbe78d38ea8a7f8cb144a479657680c03f961f1424c8527b.json
    2/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-07$259946c1fbf2884ae74748db78723bde9e9ad15cdc6fb66c882d9c5a8d6b69e3.json
    3/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2014$4eccda8fcda875865caa21e02f44b68b04aabe8703dca0c33f97e3b2c875cc23.json
    4/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2019-10$0118bd0f4425f85122390c20789ca8974db07de59f318a7a32716c3b3b1fdb3c.json
    5/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-01$fff123ed297a9c51717b3620cc2df64a95f192d9cb2d2533505ba0333580fdb7.json
    6/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2015$336d1044409cd7cb78fa08dddb2cf8039f0ffd10e3bd3a4491ce878218a0043c.json
    7/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2016$48bce800c9590d0bddd9e52be42323c696cda4a25e598c6ffad96a2a8b394646.json
    8/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-04$bdd0ca73a9bde9a9eece92e985192223507ac0e0e61df1ef487eae3c16d78e1d.json
    9/11:       http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2017$91b0c72ad31434857805c37425563a5be8f6fad00c79100aed72317106e91a8d.json
    10/11:      http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2018$e848f828f037d4c7a59ef9f5c57bb4145552f2a65809b32933ba25cb6a221820.json
    11/11:      http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2019$177ae87a95a123b7b2b325c44f5efb94b2fbaeaba33239fffe010cec94f4c743.json
    Finished: success: 11, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 11
Running 1.10.10 (2020-08-03 11:35:19) with PHP 7.1.33-16+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 on Linux / 4.15.0-64-generic
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019-10.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-01.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-04.json into cache
^BWriting /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-07.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-ralouphie$getallheaders.json from cache
Using version ^3.0 for ralouphie/getallheaders
./composer.json has been updated
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): hg branch
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): fossil branch list
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): fossil tag list
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment): svn info --xml
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin Hirak\Prestissimo\Plugin_composer_tmp0
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
    1/4:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-latest$eb9f98444c1864e0e3d84c7477cec3149da4201114560cbc6d8125859aeb33e1.json
    2/4:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-07$59bdd46b979080c87b3da8b15148152c2f1fc4eaba495fdcd7417fde75857c43.json
    3/4:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-01$da305ff39fe71daf7a4c7cd8b724246b0890976aed9cc2e3e711cd988bde37ad.json
    4/4:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-04$5c3949e643ed4d0e9543eac8fcd9ec6a0abbb773156a81d0cab000b218440a5a.json
    Finished: success: 4, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 4
Loading composer repositories with package information
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019-10.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-01%24da305ff39fe71daf7a4c7cd8b724246b0890976aed9cc2e3e711cd988bde37ad.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-01.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-04.json into cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-07.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-ralouphie$getallheaders.json from cache
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.

Dependency resolution completed in 0.000 seconds
Analyzed 103 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 88 rules to resolve dependencies
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: ralouphie/getallheaders:3.0.3
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/files/ralouphie/getallheaders/ddc5f4c7ab3d868f5060717336a0d93475d53175.zip from cache
Loading from cache
 Extracting archiveExecuting command (CWD): unzip -qq  '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/a467de1e3835523e051c9df2e882c19b' -d '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/composer/7eebe120'
    Failed to execute (9) unzip -qq  '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/a467de1e3835523e051c9df2e882c19b' -d '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/composer/7eebe120'

[/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/a467de1e3835523e051c9df2e882c19b]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/a467de1e3835523e051c9df2e882c19b or
        /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/a467de1e3835523e051c9df2e882c19b.zip, and cannot find /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/a467de1e3835523e051c9df2e882c19b.ZIP, period.

    The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
    Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
    Failed to download ralouphie/getallheaders from dist: Could not delete /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/a467de1e3835523e051c9df2e882c19b: 
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): 
    Cloning to cache at '/home/vagrant/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-ralouphie-getallheaders.git/'
Executing command (/home/vagrant/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-ralouphie-getallheaders.git/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/home/vagrant/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-ralouphie-getallheaders.git/): git rev-parse --quiet --verify '120b605dfeb996808c31b6477290a714d356e822^{commit}'
Cloning 120b605dfeb996808c31b6477290a714d356e822 from cache
Executing command (CWD): git clone --no-checkout '/home/vagrant/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-ralouphie-getallheaders.git/' '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders' --dissociate --reference '/home/vagrant/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-ralouphie-getallheaders.git/' && cd '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders' && git remote set-url origin 'https://github.com/ralouphie/getallheaders.git' && git remote add composer 'https://github.com/ralouphie/getallheaders.git'
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders): git remote set-url --push origin 'git@github.com:ralouphie/getallheaders.git'
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders): git branch -r
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders): git checkout '3.0.3' --
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders): git reset --hard '120b605dfeb996808c31b6477290a714d356e822' --
    REASON: Required by the root package: Install command rule (install ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.0|install ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.1|install ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.2|install ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.3)

Reading /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment/vendor/composer/installed.json
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

And after running this command: `php7.2 $(which composer) require ralouphie/getallheaders -vvv`, the output is as follows:

```sh
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): hg branch
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): fossil branch list
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): fossil tag list
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): svn info --xml
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin Hirak\Prestissimo\Plugin
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
    1/3:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-latest$91e51fd20918010bc9eb6755005da77e51d4ca3343b3c7e78c29f228cf441572.json
    2/3:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-07$59bdd46b979080c87b3da8b15148152c2f1fc4eaba495fdcd7417fde75857c43.json
    3/3:        http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-04$5c3949e643ed4d0e9543eac8fcd9ec6a0abbb773156a81d0cab000b218440a5a.json
    Finished: success: 3, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 3
Running 1.10.10 (2020-08-03 11:35:19) with PHP 7.2.22-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 on Linux / 4.15.0-64-generic
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019-10.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-01.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-04.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-07.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-ralouphie$getallheaders.json from cache
Using version ^3.0 for ralouphie/getallheaders
./composer.json has been updated
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): hg branch
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): fossil branch list
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): fossil tag list
Executing command (/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2): svn info --xml
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin Hirak\Prestissimo\Plugin_composer_tmp0
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019-10.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-01.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-04.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-07.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-ralouphie$getallheaders.json from cache
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.

Dependency resolution completed in 0.000 seconds
Analyzed 103 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 88 rules to resolve dependencies
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: ralouphie/getallheaders:3.0.3
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/files/ralouphie/getallheaders/ddc5f4c7ab3d868f5060717336a0d93475d53175.zip from cache
Loading from cache
 Extracting archiveExecuting command (CWD): unzip -qq  '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/fd45c27f2968e6a5a56e4f234ba908a4' -d '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/composer/d6184e5e'
    Failed to execute (9) unzip -qq  '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/fd45c27f2968e6a5a56e4f234ba908a4' -d '/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/composer/d6184e5e'

[/home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/fd45c27f2968e6a5a56e4f234ba908a4]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/fd45c27f2968e6a5a56e4f234ba908a4 or
        /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/fd45c27f2968e6a5a56e4f234ba908a4.zip, and cannot find /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/ralouphie/getallheaders/fd45c27f2968e6a5a56e4f234ba908a4.ZIP, period.

    The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
    Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
    REASON: Required by the root package: Install command rule (install ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.0|install ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.1|install ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.2|install ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.3)

Reading /home/vagrant/code/Anonymous/experiment 2/vendor/composer/installed.json
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: post whole terminal session of that attempt

Comment: I bet if you look at the output in the terminal it will give you a big clue

Comment: Try adding `-vvv` to the composer install call, and post the output of the install here.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate responses. I've added the command outputs.

Comment: It seems to break after the zip command. Try `php -i | grep -i zip` to make sure that the zip packages are installed.

Comment: @aynber, Yes; zip is installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened! But when I ran this commands: `php7.2 $(which composer) clear-cache` and then `php7.2 $(which composer) require ralouphie/getallheaders -vvv`, it successfully installed that package.

Thanks @Marcin Orlowski, @RiggsFolly and @aynber for your help!